# Few things about Repository Pattern that I simply don't understand

Tags: repository-pattern, data-access-layer

I've read quite a few topic on what Repository is, but there are still few things bugging me.

To my understanding only difference between *Repository* and *traditional data access layers* are *Repository's* query construction capabilities ( ie *Query Object pattern*). But when reading the following definitions of a *Repository Pattern*, it seems we can still have *Repository* even if we don't implement *Query Object pattern*:

a)
[From:](http://blog.lowendahl.net/?p=249)

> Repositories are the single point where we hand off and fetch objects.
>   It is also the boundary where communication with the storage starts
>   and ends.

I think above quote suggests that *Repository* is an entry point into DAL.  In other words, according to the quote, the DAL consumer (say *Service layer*) comunicates with DAL via *Repository*. But shouldn't instead *data context* represent an entry point into DAL ( thus *Repository* should reside within *data context* )?

b)
[From:](http://devlicio.us/blogs/casey/archive/2009/02/20/ddd-the-repository-pattern.aspx)

> The primary thing that differentiates a Repository from a traditional
>   data access layer is that it is to all intents and purposes a
>   Collection semantic – just like IList in .Net

Don't most traditional DALs also have methods that return a collection (for example `List<Customer> GetAllCustomers()`)? So how exactly is a collection-like semantic of a *Repository* any different from collection-like semantic of a traditional DAL?

c) 
[From:](http://www.sapiensworks.com/blog/post/2012/02/22/The-Repository-Pattern-Explained.aspx)

> In a nutshell, the Repository pattern means abstracting the
>   persistence layer, masking it as a collection. This way the
>   application doesn't care about databases and other persistence
>   details, it only deals with the abstraction (which usually is coded as
>   an interface).

As far as I know, the above definition isn't any different from the definition of a *traditional DAL*.
Thus, if *Repository* implementation only performed two functions – having the collection-like semantics and isolating the domain objects from details of the database access code – how  would it be any different from a *traditional DAL*? In other words, would/should it still be called *Repository*?

d) 
What makes the following interface a *Repository interface* instead of just a regular *DAL interface*?

[From:](http://www.sapiensworks.com/blog/post/2012/02/22/The-Repository-Pattern-Explained.aspx)

```
public interface IPostsRepository
    {
        void Save(Post mypost);
        Post Get(int id);
        PaginatedResult<Post> List(int skip,int pageSize);
        PaginatedResult<Post> SearchByTitle(string title,int skip,int pageSize);
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

FYI I asked a very similar question [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180501/what-specific-issue-does-the-repository-pattern-solve) and got some excellent answers.

The bottom line is it appears to depend on the complexity of your architecture. The repository pattern is most useful to create a layer of abstraction when you need to access different *types* of data stores, i.e. some data is in entity framework, some is on the file system, etc. In simpler web apps with a (probably unchanging) single data store (i.e. all data in SQL Server, or Oracle, etc) it is less important. At that point something like the Entity Framework context object functions as a repository for your entity objects.