# Is there a reason for using the Repository pattern with Entity Framework if I know I will only ever use EF?

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern

From reading various books and articles, I seem to rather often find the usage of the Repository-pattern suggested. I get the point if you need to be able to swap out your data layer from one to another, but my question is, if I know with 100% certainty that I will *not* use any other tech for data access, is there any reason for using said pattern?

The thing that I find myself doubting the most is that I don't really see what this extra layer of abstraction can bring to the table in this scenario. From my experience, EF with its fluent linq-to-entities -functionality should be more than enough for pretty much all my needs.

The most usual cases seem to start the repositories with methods such as FindAll, Find, Add and Delete, all of which are very easily accessible directly through EF (so no code duplication to speak of).

So am I just missing some big point, or is the repository more for when you need to support multiple different data access technologies?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They are many opinions on the issue but after using repositories for 2 projects, i never tried it again.

Too much pain with hundreds of methods for all those cases with no clear benefits (i'm almost never going to swap out EF for another ORM).

The best advice would be to try it out so you can make an informed opinion on which route to take.

Some opinions against it [here](http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton)

Comment: Ok, so pretty much what I kind of expected. The article was also a good clarification. Thanks.

Comment: I want to add that I'm also reaching back around to where i started and actually dissolving my current repository in favor of just accessing everything from UnitOfWork or my Business logic - I don't wnat to get flamed for this but basically... isn't EF acting as a repository anyway?

Answer (score 13):

I think you're on the right direction. I asked myself the same question two years ago after I've used the repository pattern in some projects. I came to the conclusion that hiding your ORM behind a repository implemented on top of your ORM will get you nothing but unnecessary work. In addition to implementing meaningless FindAll, Find, Add ... methods you would loose some performance optimization possibilities that the ORM gives you. Or at least it will get quite hard to apply some of those methods.

So if you're not going to switch your ORM within the lifetime of your project, I don't see any benefits in applying the repository pattern.

So instead of preparing for the situation where one could in future easily switch the ORM, I would suggest to do some more investigation upfront, wisely choose an ORM, stick with it and stay away from the repository pattern.

Comment: I really had the same experience stay away from the generic repo pattern.

Comment: Agree, many peoples hype the repository design to think the project is well structure , however, to keep the project simple is what meaning of well structure. Making unnecessary repo, service, interface, implement on top of EF is just abstract of abstract. I have work on Spring Boot, most tutorials teaching peoples use repository pattern, just because Spring Data is implement of Hibernate/JPA, which don't have any official tools to generate the some like EF entity model.

Answer (score 6):

What people don't realize is that EF is already a Repository and a Unit-of-Work.

Repository has recently become an anti-pattern. Never use a design pattern because its *cool* or trendy or trying to build your resume, in fact this should be a standard rule for all design patterns.

Only build a Repository and Unit-of-Work on top of EF if your application is

- very large (lasagna layer)
- long-lived (10 years or so)
- has more than 5 developers working in parallel
- has developers that are separated geographically
- requires a lot of maintenance
- multiple data access infrastructures

A good indication is when upgrading from EF5 to EF6 requires you to knock on everybody's door.

Comment: Thanks for this, this clarifies a lot of my confusion. I guess I should rename my "repository" class to "services" or something haha

Answer (score 4):

I'm not as hot on the repository pattern as I used to be, but I still find it can be useful in the following scenarios (assuming swapping the ORM isn't one of them):

- Unit testing (assuming you'd rather mock or stub than use Sqlite or hit a real db)
- Being able to stub out data access during development via a repository that has an in-memory IEnumerable as its backing source.

Comment: With EF 6 you can do mocking/unit testing easily. So there is no more a reason to use the terrible generic repo pattern: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx#options

Answer (score 1):

I am actually in *disagreement* that EF is a *correct* example of a "Repository Pattern". It is a *typed Data Access Layer* and an *exposed LINQ implementation*.

Please note that if one fully endorses EF as "the business domain" then the above does not hold; however, I use EF - as poorly as it does - with Schema First, in which EF is *not* the strict business domain. The term "*correct*" is used to reinforce this viewpoint - adjust for your own perspective / design.

A *correct* Repository Pattern, in my book, exposes aggregate roots of *relevant* operations. That is, the implementation details (EF) is kept *within* the Repository, as much as possible. That is, the Repository takes care of the mapping of the *relevant* Domain objects to the underlying model.

This is an agreement with how Microsoft defines [The Repository Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) - note that the *business entities* are mapped to a data source. (And thus my fundamental disagreement with EF fulfilling this role: EF *only* has a chance of sanely maps business entities when designed from Code First.)

The best summation / article I have found is [Repository pattern, done right](http://blog.gauffin.org/2013/01/repository-pattern-done-right/) by Gauffin. While he approaches the Repository pattern from a more extreme view than I, here are some key points as to why EF's simply bleeds through an Active Record / ORM pattern.

Here are some selected excerpts that highlight why I do *not* thing that EF is a proper implementation of a Repository Pattern.

> The repository pattern is an abstraction. *It’s purpose is to reduce complexity and make the rest of the code persistent ignorant. As a bonus it allows you to write unit tests instead of integration tests.* The problem is that many developers fail to understand the patterns purpose - and create repositories [ie. EF] which leak persistence specific information up to the caller
>
> ..
>
> *Using repositories is not about being able to switch persistence technology* (i.e. changing database or using a web service etc instead) .. Repository pattern do allow you to do that, but it’s not the main purpose.
>
> ..
>
> When people talks about Repository pattern and unit tests they are not saying that the pattern allows you to use unit tests for the data access layer .. If you use ORM/LINQ in your business logic you can never be sure why the tests fail.
>
> ..
>
> Do note that the repository pattern is only useful if you have POCOs which are mapped using code first. Otherwise you’ll just break the abstraction using the entities. [That is, only EF Code First can even attempt to meet this requirement.]
>
> ..
>
> Building a correct repository implementation is very easy. In fact, you only have to follow a single rule: *Do not add anything into the repository class until the very moment that you need it*

And if you *do* use EF as a Repository - I believe it's still a typed DAL, as much as it bleeds - please do not try to hide it in a "more generic" pattern - a Repository pattern is *not about type unification*, it is about exposing aggregate roots for a particular context and operations on such.

See [What specific issue does the repository pattern solve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180501/what-specific-issue-does-the-repository-pattern-solve/13189143#13189143) as well.

---

While I speek *against* EF being a *correct* Repository Pattern - it is the Active Record pattern - I am not a Repository purist. That is there are cases when I will bleed EF (or L2S) entities in *specific cases*; I accept this as *technical debt*. Just understand the cost of breaking such a Repository / Domain boundary.